# Difference between pypi.org UI and pip output

Tags: pip, pypi

Where does this differences come from?

There's tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.36.0 available on https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem/

[image]

but pip cannot find version 0.36.0

```
$ $ python3.8 -m pip install tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.36.0 --extra-index-url=https://pypi.org/simple
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.org/simple

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.36.0 (from versions: 0.18.0, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.20.0, 0.21.0, 0.22.0, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.24.0, 0.25.0, 0.26.0, 0.27.0, 0.28.0, 0.29.0, 0.30.0, 0.31.0, 0.32.0, 0.33.0, 0.34.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.36.0
```

Where does this discrepancy come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're using Python<3.9. Looking at the [available files to download](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem/0.36.0/#files), 0.36.0 has wheels only for Python 3.9 and above.

EDIT: I'm blind. No need to suspect which python version you're using, as you're calling pip using python3.8

Comment: Good spot, I was misled by `Requires: Python >=3.7, <3.12` in documentation. Also this version range is given in https://github.com/tensorflow/io/blob/master/setup.py#L155